# Can we express future tense with simple tense?

Tags: sentence-construction

Which sentence is correct to say? And when?

> a - If I do this, I hope she forgives me.
>   b - If I do this, I hope she will forgive me.

One more example

> c - OK, I check that and send you again.
>   d - OK, I will check that and send you again.

Comment: "send you" means "I will direct you to go somewhere". Do you mean "I will send it to you"?

Answer (score 1):

In order for the simple present to indicate the future there must be some other information in the sentence that places the context in the future.

**Example 1**
In the first example both options are correct, have the same meaning and can be used interchangeably. The verb 'forgive' is in the future in both cases because of the conditional nature of the sentences. Both sentences start with 'If I do this'. 'This' hasn't been done yet, so the forgiveness that results from doing 'this' must be in the future. So even though 'forgives' looks like it's in the simple present in the first option, it's really in the future.

[Simple Present as Future](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/simple-present-future-events/)

**Example 2b**
In the second example, option b is correct by itself. Because it starts with 'OK', we assume it's part of a conversation and the speaker has just been given some new information that he or she is expected to respond to. The speaker uses the future tense 'will' to describe what his or her response will be before actually doing it.

**Example 2a**
The second option a sounds incorrect by itself, without context. The way it's written there's no other information in the sentence referring to the future, so the simple form can't serve as the future tense.

The only way the second option a would be correct is if you're describing what happens habitually.

> Whenever you come back empty handed, I check that and send you again.

or if there's something else in it that indicates the future

> OK, I might check that and send you again.

Comment: "send you again" isn't actually good English. "send it to you again" would be correct. It might be idiomatic in Indian English but I'm not sure.

Comment: Well, OK... if you mean you're going to send an actual person, that's fine... "If you don't come home from the store with eggs, I'm going to send you again"... but I don't think that's what's going on in the question... it begs for some sort of object.

Comment: @Catija Yes, I meant it in the sense of, 'Send you again to whatever place you went before.' I think the examples could be interpreted in several different ways, depending on context that we don't have. I tried to imagine contexts that made them complete as they were. We've had to make a lot of assumptions just to get this question into an answerable form already, so I hope my further assumptions will be acceptable. The crux of the question is about the tense.

Comment: @Catija What are you seeing that leads you to conclude there's something different going on in the question and how would you suggest changing my examples?

Comment: There's no context in the question, which always makes things confusing. Yes, the focus is on the tense but getting clarification about what the OP's actually trying to say is always a good idea and possibly the second example really needs it for that part of the question to be really answered. A request for clarification already exists, so we'll see what they say. The only "assumption" that was made earlier was adding "I"... that's not really "a lot".

Comment: Agreed. I'll adjust it if necessary once the OP answers above.

Answer (score 0):

According to [**this**](https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/simple-present-future-events/), present simple can be used to refer to the future:

> The simple present is used to make statements about events at a time later than now, when the statements are based on present facts, and when these facts are something fixed like a time-table, schedule, calendar.
>
> Examples
>
> - The plane **arrives** at 18.00 tomorrow.
> - She **has** a yoga class tomorrow morning.
> - The restaurant **opens** at 19.30 tonight.
> - Next Thursday at 14.00 **there is** an English exam.
> - The plane **leaves** in ten minutes.

Therefore, your sentences a and b are OK.

In sentences c and d, you should use "... and send **it to** you again."

However, sentence c gives the feeling that you are currently checking (maybe pausing shortly for writing an email). If that is not true (the checking is not started), then sentence d is better.

Answer (score -1):

For the first one, always go with a. Also, in general it would be better to just say "I hope she will forgive me if I do this", because in writing you  should try to avoid using the passive voice.

For the second, b is correct. In order for A to be correct, since the sentence  overall is future,  but check is present, it will need to be changed to future, as done in b.

Comment: What is wrong with the first B choice, assuming that there is an 'I' before hope, the sentence seems perfectly fine for speaking or writing to me. I also don't know where you're seeing the passive voice. Both sentences are in the active voice.

Comment: The first b leaves ambiguity about who is hoping she will forgive him. To native English speakers, it may be obvious, but for someone who is just starting to learn, an implied subject like that may not be understood. About the passive thing, looking at it more, I was incorrect about it. It is perfectly okay in the state that it is.

Comment: I understand. I'm assuming that ambiguity is a mistake and not really important to the question, which is about simple vs. future. BTW, since it looks like you might be new to this site, it's a good idea to change your answer if you agree with an issue that's been pointed out in the comments. That way the information you're providing the questioner is accurate and up to date, and your answer is less likely to get voted down.

Comment: Passive voice is not in general bad, and I don't see any passive voice in any of the sentences presented by the OP.

Comment: You're confusing passive voice with being vague about agency.  They're two different things, and passives can even be used to *emphasize* the agent by shifting it to the end of the sentence: *Don't you see?  The patient was killed **by his own doctor**!*